# My code for autorole doesn't work and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { Client,  Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: ["DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS"],
    presence: {
        status: "online",
        activities: [{
            name: "markets",
            type: "WATCHING"
        }]
    },
});

client.on('ready', () => { 
    console.log(`Launched as a bot: ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    function roleAdd() {
        member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.SERVER_ROLE_ID));
    }
    roleAdd();
});

client.login(process.env.DJS_TOKEN);
```

Guys I wrote this code but it is not working. I am not getting any errors. I want it to add a role whenever a user joins to my server. the status of the bot is working. I think the issue is on the `guildMemberAdd` part.

Comment: log `member.guild.roles.cache.get(..)` and remove function

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure why you're using the approach of nested functions for this. If you want the event to call the function move the function outside of the event and then create the `GuildMember` in a parameter.

Or discard the event entirely and leave the plain `#<GuildMemberRoleManager>.add` method by itself.

I suggest the latter as I assume the nested function declaration wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use auto role add for your server, try the easiest method to do the role add, same way as giving role to a member

When you giving a role to specific member should look like this:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === process.env.SERVER_ROLE_ID)
const target = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

If a bot giving a role `higher than the bot or equal to bot`. You will get an error such as **Missing Permissions** To prevent this you need to put a code to return it

```
if(!target.moderatable) return message.reply("I can't mute this person!")
```

This command is a same way for auto give role, just a few code lines ***added/edited/removed***.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
function roleAdd() {
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.SERVER_ROLE_ID));
}
roleAdd();
});
```

```
- function roleAdd() {}
+ let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == process.env.SERVER_ROLE_ID)
+ member.roles.add(role).catch()
```

The `.catch()` line is to prevent on giving error and shutdown your bot.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == process.env.SERVER_ROLE_ID)
member.roles.add(role).catch()
});
```